# Python Stay on Element In For Loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, try-except

I'd like to know how I can somehow stay on one Element until the next loop cycle in a for loop. here's a code example:

```
for element in numbers:
    try:
        ...
    except:
        # It should stay on this element for the next time
        pass
```

So as example, I have

```
numbers = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']
```

Now I'm on the element Banana as example, and If that error comes up, It should just stay on banana until the next cycle, so the expected output would be: apple, banana (error), banana (now It tries again), peach.

Comment: A `for` loop simply will not do that - each iteration gets the next element from the iterable you're looping over.  You'd need an inner loop (a `while` loop, perhaps) that repeatedly uses the `for` loop value until you're done with it.

Comment: @jasonharper Could you give me a Code example on how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop to iterate on the indexes:

```
i = 0
while i < len(numbers):
    element = numbers[i]
    try:
        ...
        i+=1
    except:
        # It should stay on this element for the next time
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with regular for loops as far as I know. You can get something similar by controlling the iterating variable directly:

```
i = 0
while i < len(numbers):
  try:
    # Do work
    numbers[i] ....
    i += 1
  except:
    # Don't increment i
    pass
```

Just be careful because you can get stuck in infinite loops with this if "banana" never succeeds.

Comment: The one with Banan was just an example, I have an error that will work after a certain period of time, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a simple while loop inside the for loop:

```
for element in numbers:
    while True:
        try:
            ...
            break  # Success; break out of the while to the next element.
        except:
            # It should stay on this element for the next time
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `while` inside the `for` to keep processing the element until you are happy. This could end up in an infinite loop, so code wisely.

```
numbers = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']

i_hate_bananas = True

for element in numbers:
    while True:
        try:
            if i_hate_bananas and element == 'banana':
                raise ValueError(f'{element}, yuck')
            print("I like", element)
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            i_hate_bananas = False
print('done')
```

This may be better than just having a single `while` and increment an indexer to `numbers` because it works with iteration and thus with any iterable.